# Why Treasury Yield Bond 10 Years is rising?

Tags: stock-markets, bonds

A few questions on the Treasury Bond 10 Years:

1. What is contributing to the rise of Treasury Yield Bond 10 Years? Is it caused by some economic activity like selling or buying bonds by the US Central Bank / Fed?
2. How the Treasury Bond Yield 10 Years is related to inflation rate?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this because questions asking why a specific security is going up or down are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yield rises in opposition to the price of the security, so in this case the simple answer is that there's either soft demand for 10-year treasuries or there's enough selling volume to outstrip demand, hence the price of the bond continues to fall and drives up the yield.

The interest rate paid on a bond is called the "coupon" rate, and it is a fixed number.  In the case of the 10-year bond, Bloomberg says it's 1.13%.

The current yield (as of 3/18/21) is 1.19%, with 10-year bonds trading at 94.70, or 94.70 cents on the dollar.

*Current yield* on a bond is calculated by dividing the annual interest rate by the bond price.

*Yield to maturity* is a bit more complex:

((Annual Interest Payment)+((Face Value-Current Price)/(Years to Maturity))) / ((Face Value + Current Price)/2)

If you buy the bond below par then you're still cashed out at 100 cents on the dollar when the bond is redeemed, and you're also receiving the full interest on the bond as if you'd paid par for it, even though you paid less than par.  Using today's numbers, if you bought a $1,000 10-year bond paying 1.13%, you would only pay $947 for it.  But your $947 would earn interest at the same rate as though you'd paid $1,000 for the bond, so your effective yield would be 1.709% to maturity.